# youtube api - waiting for video

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I made a bot that waits for videos from several channels and sends new ones to telegram.. Here is the code:

```py
from distutils.log import error
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import config
import time

import telebot
ChannelsAndVideos = []
Channels = config.channels_id
bot_token = config.bot_token
api_key = config.api_key
sleepTime = config.sleepTime
messageText = config.messageText
telegram_channels_id = config.telegram_channels_id
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
sended = []
for ChannelId in Channels:
    try:
        request = youtube.channels().list(
            part='statistics',
            id=ChannelId
            )
        response = request.execute()
        if(response['pageInfo']['totalResults'] != 1):
            print("Error! Не удалось добавить " + ChannelId)
        else:
            print(ChannelId + " был добавлен (" + response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount') + " видео)")
            ChannelsAndVideos.append((ChannelId, response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount')))
    except error:
        print(error.message)
while(True):
    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    for i in range(len(ChannelsAndVideos)):
        request = youtube.channels().list(
            part='statistics',
            id=ChannelsAndVideos[i][0]
        )
        response = request.execute()
        if(response['pageInfo']['totalResults'] != 1):
            print("Error!")
        else:
            if response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount') > ChannelsAndVideos[i][1]:
                ChannelsAndVideos[i] = (ChannelsAndVideos[i][0], response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount'))
                request = youtube.channels().list(
                    part='contentDetails',
                    id=ChannelsAndVideos[i][0]
                    )
                response = request.execute()
                request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                part=['contentDetails','snippet','status'],
                playlistId=response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
                )
                response = request.execute()
                if not (response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'] in sended):
                    sended.append(response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
                    for chat_id in telegram_channels_id:
                       try:
                            bot.send_message(chat_id, messageText + "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
                       except ...:
                           print("Не удалось отправить сообщение в " + str(chat_id))
```

There is a problem in its implementation: every 30 seconds it makes a request for the latest videos of each channel, so this eats up RAM and the rest of possible requests (their number is limited in the youtube api). How can I optimize this system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reducing memory usage

> ```py
>  sended = []
>  ...
>                 if not (response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'] in sended):
>                     sended.append(response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
> ```

To avoid the ever growing list of sent videos, use a set. It will also improve the runtime complexity of `['videoId'] in sended` from O(n) to O(1).

```py
sended = set()
...
                if not (response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'] in sended):
                    sended.add(response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
```

#### Rate limiting

> ```py
> while(True):
>     time.sleep(sleepTime)
>     for i in range(len(ChannelsAndVideos)):
>         request = youtube.channels().list(
> ```

Instead of `sleep`ing in big chunk before iterating the channels, `sleep` before each request to the api. For easy usage, create a helper `request` function which will ensure at least `sleepTime` delay before the next request.

```py
last_request_time = time.time()
def execute(request)
    global last_request_time
    next_request_time = last_request_time + sleepTime
    time.sleep(max(next_request_time - time.time(), 0))
    last_request_time = time.time()
    return request.execute()
```

Now replace all `request.execute()`s with `execute(request)`. Adjust `sleepTime` value based on YouTube api usage limits and remove all `time.sleep(sleepTime)`.

#### Result

```py
from distutils.log import error
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import config
import time

import telebot
ChannelsAndVideos = []
Channels = config.channels_id
bot_token = config.bot_token
api_key = config.api_key
sleepTime = config.sleepTime
messageText = config.messageText
telegram_channels_id = config.telegram_channels_id
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

sended = set()


last_request_time = 0
def execute(request)
    global last_request_time
    next_request_time = last_request_time + sleepTime
    time.sleep(max(next_request_time - time.time(), 0))
    last_request_time = time.time()
    return request.execute()


for ChannelId in Channels:
    try:
        request = youtube.channels().list(
            part='statistics',
            id=ChannelId
            )
        response = execute(request)
        if(response['pageInfo']['totalResults'] != 1):
            print(‎"Error! Failed to add "‎ + ChannelId)
        else:
            print(ChannelId + ‎" has been added ("‎ + response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount') + ‎" video)"‎)
            ChannelsAndVideos.append((ChannelId, response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount')))
    except error:
        print(error.message)

while(True):
    for i in range(len(ChannelsAndVideos)):
        request = youtube.channels().list(
            part='statistics',
            id=ChannelsAndVideos[i][0]
        )
        response = execute(request)
        if(response['pageInfo']['totalResults'] != 1):
            print("Error!")
        else:
            if response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount') > ChannelsAndVideos[i][1]:
                ChannelsAndVideos[i] = (ChannelsAndVideos[i][0], response.get('items')[0].get('statistics').get('videoCount'))
                request = youtube.channels().list(
                    part='contentDetails',
                    id=ChannelsAndVideos[i][0]
                    )
                response = execute(request)
                request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                part=['contentDetails','snippet','status'],
                playlistId=response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
                )
                response = execute(request)
                if not (response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'] in sended):
                    sended.add(response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
                    for chat_id in telegram_channels_id:
                       try:
                            bot.send_message(chat_id, messageText + "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
                       except ...:
                           print(‎"Failed to send message to "‎ + str(chat_id))
```